# Beamer preventing display of headlines

Tags: beamer, header-footer

Can we prevent the display of headlines only but retain the footers for a particular slide in beamer?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redefine the `beamer` template `headline` to be empty, inside a group, for the selected frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\begingroup
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\endgroup

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]